# Populating a new column based on the values in existing two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have an Excel with format:

```
A      B
true  false
false true 
false false
```

I need to add a new column C whose value is populated based on an existing column. 
The condition which I need to follow is:

```
if ($A=true then $C= M), if ($A=false and $B= true then $C=T) , else $C= R
```

Can anyone please help me out with the syntax for these types of queries?

Comment: In cell C1: `=IF(A1,"M",IF(B1,"T","R"))`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, copying @Phylogenesis' Comment:

```
>In cell C1: =IF(A1,"M",IF(B1,"T","R"))
```